# Is it necessary to calculate the flux for sensorless control of a PMSM?

Tags: motor, control-system, pmsm

For sensorless control of a PMSM, I require just the position estimation to replace the encoder. Further parameters such as speed can be calculated from position.

However, in many places I notice the flux observer based methods compute position as the atan(Ψβ/Ψα). Why not directly use just the currents to get position as  atan(Iβ/Iα)?

[image: Upper plot is using flux and bottom uses only current]
Upper plot is using flux and bottom uses only current

Simulink results show the current based angle calculation is sufficient. Doesn't calculating flux to compute position need both current and voltage data? This seems to add to computation time and circuitry.

I do notice that torque calculation requires flux to be calculated. But to my knowledge, for torque control just the iq current is required to be measured and obtained via Park/Clarke from the phase currents. So I don't think even torque calculation is needed.

Please clarify. TIA!